# What algorithm to use to optimize an expensive multi-variable function that is known to be dominated by a term depending only on the first few inputs?

Tags: optimization, approximation, numerical-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I have an expensive-to-evaluate high-dimensional ($n=22$) objective function $f$ that I need to minimize numerically without taking derivatives. The function $f$ can be expressed as a sum of several functions $h_i$. For the sake of simplicity, lets say $n=2$, then we could express $f$ like this, but note there are many more variables and also more than two $h$-functions:
$$ f(x,y) = h_1(x) + h_2(x,y)$$
The $h_i$ have a strictly positive value set, and $h_2 < h_1$ usually holds. EDIT: more details at [1] down below.

I believe this structure of $f$ to be highly exploitable for optimization because conceptually I could do two things:

- compute $h_1(x)$ to figure out which $x$-values are sensible
- get several evaluations for $f$ out of one evaluation of $h_1$, only recomputing $h_2$

My previous attempts to optimize the function are a black-box-approach: only passing $f$ to a quality radial-basis-function-optimizer without using the hierarchical structure explained above. However, this converges very slowly, wasting lots of time with terrible $x$-values.

Is there an Optimization-Algorithm that allows me to exploit this known hierarchical structure? Alternatively, just finding out if this kind of problem has a name would probably already help greatly.

---

EDIT

*what I need*: I am looking for ideas and heuristics on algorithms. I have compared several, but they all seem to assume I can only evaluate one objective function $f$.

[1] *the functions*: $h_1$ tends to have plateaus of low value, not sharp valleys, and the choice of $x$ matters for computing $h_2$ which can not be facorized into $x$ and $y$ contributions (in any way that I know of). It is true that if $(x_0, y_0)$ minimizes $f$, then $h_1(x_0)$ must be a low value, but it does not have to be the minimum of $h_1$, just close to it.

*answering the commenters:*

- "function has a single global minimum?" -> This is a problem from engineering, it is not important if I find 'the' global minimum or just a very good solution. That being said, all input variables are bounded so suppose a global minimum should exist.
- "known upper bounds on the values of the summed functions?" -> There are and I could calculate them, though it would be much easier to estimate them.
- "more worthwile to find a tiny delta to x than a big delta to y" -> I do not have a way to calculate $h_i(x+\delta)$ from $h_i(x)$ no matter the size of the $\delta$, it is always a full recompute. Also, I very much do care about $y$, $h_2$ can not be neglected and only $(x,y)$ is a real solution to the problem.
- "doing this as a series of 1D optimizations" -> This is computationally efficient, but the solution quality will drop. The problem is that in regions where $h_1$ is low and relatively flat, I can not just pick the minimum of $h_1$ as that will constrain $h_2$ too much.

Comment: `get several evaluations for f out of one evaluation of h1, only recomputing h2` this would be exploring $y$ with a fixed $x$ -- but you said that the problem is a lot more sensitive to $x$ (through $h_1$) than $y$. In other words, it might be more worthwhile to find a tiny delta to $x$ than a big delta to $y$.

Comment: One kind of hacky thing you can do is precondition the problem, by scaling the inputs, so that sensitivity to the input variables is more uniform. You could also try doing this as a series of 1D optimizations for successive variables.

Comment: You need to tell us more, I think. Is it known that the function has a single global minimum? The answer is required to be a / the global minimum? Are there known upper bounds on the values of the summed functions?

Comment: @AlexK I have updated the question to adress your points. Do you think successive 1D-optimization could work if the output of the 1D-optimization would not be a point but a region somehow? Lets say finds a region $\Omega$ where $x \in \Omega \implies h_1(x_0) - h_1(x) < \epsilon$ with $x_0$ being the arg-minimum of $h_1$? Are there such algorithms?

Comment: @RonKaminsky I edited the question to include your points.

Comment: I don't think that you will manage to do better than optimizing in two stages, one where you replace $f$ with a function which remembers all $x$ values where $h_1$ has been evaluated and checks if the new $x$ value is in the convex hull of the known ones and if so approximates $h_1$ using interpolation (otherwise evaluating $h_1$), and then switching over to using the real $f$ once you are close enough to a local minimum. For the convex hull check, the answer at URL https://stackoverflow.com/a/43564754/712173 might be useful.